# Perl: Accessing part of a JSON query

Tags: json, perl, parsing

I have been writing part of a website I'm making, part of the stats page will display information about a websites Json response.

The address of the website is: http://steamcommunity.com/market/listings/440/Name%20Tag/render/?count=1&start=1&query=.

Here is a link to a parser so the code is easier to read http://json.parser.online.fr/.

The code I have written so far works but no matter what i try I cant get the information I need.

```
use JSON::XS;
use WWW::Mechanize;
use HTTP::Cookies;
use LWP::Simple;
use strict;
use warnings;

my $url = "http://steamcommunity.com/market/listings/440/Name%20Tag/render/?count=2&start=2";
my $json = get $url;
my $data = decode_json $json;
my $info = $data -> {listinginfo};
```

My problem is that i would like to access the price of the listing however when new listings are made available the reference for them changes. I have no idea how to deal with this and Google is not helping. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance.

Seb Morris.

EDIT: Thanks for the replies, I have progressed my code and ended up with:

```
my $data = decode_json $json;
my @infoids = keys %{$data -> {listinginfo}};

foreach my $infoid (@infoids) {
my $price = $data -> {listinginfo}{$infoid}{converted_price};
print "$price" . "\n";
}
```

However I am getting the error: Use of uninitialized value $price in string at line 30. I dont understand why I am getting this error as I have declared the variable. Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by 'the reference for them changes'?

Comment: inside of the listinginfo object the object names change as the website changes, this happens quite often. I dont know how to deal with this and just look and the first object within the main object.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand, your problem is that the listinginfo object contains key(s) which change for each request, and you don't know to find out what the key is for the request you just made.

You can find the keys to a perl hash using the 'keys' function. So you can get all of the keys of the listinginfo hash like this:

```
my @infoids = keys %{$data -> {listinginfo}};
```

Note the need to use %{ } to de-reference listinfo, which is itself a hash reference.

There could be more than one info ID, although when I tested the web service you linked in your question it only ever returned one. If you are sure there will only ever be one, you can use:

```
my $price = $data -> {listinginfo}{$infoids[0]}{price};
```

Or, if there might be more than one, you can loop through them:

```
foreach my $infoid (@infoids) {
    my $price = $data -> {listinginfo}{$infoids[0]}{price};
    # Now do something with price
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, the code looks good but when i execute it I get a run-time error: Can't call method "keys" on unblessed reference. Really what I want is to be able to print some of the values in listing info, specifically; price, listing id and within the object assets (which is in listing info) the currency. I cant seem to be able to bend my head around the problem. Thanks in advance.